# Linking Sets and Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project in Python which requires lookup of set values in a dictionary.

I have two dictionaries, both with ID as the key.  One dictionary has names as the values, and the other has emails as the values.

For example:

```
Names Dictionary:

{'cbp750': 'Crystle Purifoy', 'mis918': 'Marquita See', 'bmb865': 'Bok 
 Bobbitt', 'dch273': 'Danny Halverson', 'etf890': 'Elvia Fortin', 'nve360':
 'Nakisha Ehrmann'}


Emails Dictionary:

{'cbp750': 'c.purifoy@utexas.edu', 'mis918': 'm.see@utexas.edu', 'bmb865':
 'b.bobbitt@utexas.edu', 'dch273': 'd.halverson@utexas.edu', 'etf890':
 'e.fortin@utexas.edu', 'nve360':'n.ehrmann@utexas.edu'}
```

If I have a set of values, such as: `{'mis918', 'etf890', 'nve360'}`, how do I look up these set values in the dictionaries to return the name and email in the format Name(Email) such that looking up `mis918` would return `Marquita See (M.See@utexas.edu)`?

My current attempts to use for loops have failed, so I have no idea where I should start.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do share your failing loop attempts. Looping over a set is trivial and no different from looping over a list or a string.

Comment: `for ID in ids_set: print(Names[ID], Emails[ID], sep=': ')` is but a simple example.

Comment: You're essentially wanting to perform a JOIN operation on the two dictionaries.  What do you want to happen if a key exists in the names dict but not the emails? And vise versa?

Comment: All keys appear in both the names and emails dictionaries for the purposes of this project

Comment: @EarthlingPerson, Was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you can just access a dictionary value by passing in the key:

```
names = {
    'cbp750': 'Crystle Purifoy',
    'mis918': 'Marquita See',
    'bmb865': 'Bok Bobbitt',
    'dch273': 'Danny Halverson',
    'etf890': 'Elvia Fortin',
    'nve360': 'Nakisha Ehrmann'
}

emails = {
    'cbp750': 'c.purifoy@utexas.edu',
    'mis918': 'm.see@utexas.edu',
    'bmb865': 'b.bobbitt@utexas.edu',
    'dch273': 'd.halverson@utexas.edu',
    'etf890': 'e.fortin@utexas.edu',
    'nve360':'n.ehrmann@utexas.edu'
}


set_of_ids =  {'mis918', 'etf890', 'nve360'}

for _id in set_of_ids:
    if _id in names and _id in emails:
        print('{} ({})'.format(names[_id], emails[_id]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access an item from the `dict`, you can pass `key` as `dict[key]` to access it's value. In your case, key is the item in `set`. Iterate over your `set` and use the `item` as key for fetching the values from `email_dict` and `name_dict`.

**Note:** In case there is possibility that the item in the `set` may not be the `key` in `dict`, use `dict.get(key, '')` instead. It will return the value as `''` empty string for unknown keys. For example:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': 2}
>>> my_dict.get('a', '')  # Returns value as 'a' is key in 'my_dict'
2 
>>> my_dict.get('b', '')  # Return empty string as 'b' is not key in 'my_dict'
''
```

Below is the sample code for your issue (assuming all `item` in `set` are present in your both `dict`):

```
my_set = {'mis918', 'etf890', 'nve360'}
for item in my_set:
    print('Set Value: ', item, ' ; Email: ', email_dict[item], ' ; Name: ', name_dict[item])

# Output of above code 
Set Value:  etf890  ; Email:  e.fortin@utexas.edu  ; Name:  Elvia Fortin
Set Value:  mis918  ; Email:  m.see@utexas.edu  ; Name:  Marquita See
Set Value:  nve360  ; Email:  n.ehrmann@utexas.edu  ; Name:  Nakisha Ehrmann
```

where `email_dict` and `name_dict` are dict as are mentioned in question, i.e:

```
name_dict = {
        'cbp750': 'Crystle Purifoy', 
        'mis918': 'Marquita See', 
        'bmb865': 'BokBobbitt', 
        'dch273': 'Danny Halverson', 
        'etf890': 'Elvia Fortin', 
        'nve360': 'Nakisha Ehrmann'
    }

email_dict = {
        'cbp750': 'c.purifoy@utexas.edu', 
        'mis918': 'm.see@utexas.edu', 
        'bmb865': 'b.bobbitt@utexas.edu', 
        'dch273': 'd.halverson@utexas.edu', 
        'etf890': 'e.fortin@utexas.edu',                  
        'nve360':'n.ehrmann@utexas.edu'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A short one liner answer would be:

```
# names -> name dictionary, emails -> email dictionary, idSet -> contains ids to be searched.

['{} ({})'.format(names[idx], emails[idx]) for idx in idSet if idx in names and idx in emails]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach to get the expected result (using `re.sub` function to format local part of email):

```
import re

names = {'cbp750': 'Crystle Purifoy', 'mis918': 'Marquita See', 'bmb865': 'Bok  Bobbitt', 'dch273': 'Danny Halverson', 'etf890': 'Elvia Fortin', 'nve360': 'Nakisha Ehrmann'}

emails = {'cbp750': 'c.purifoy@utexas.edu', 'mis918': 'm.see@utexas.edu',\
          'bmb865': 'b.bobbitt@utexas.edu', 'dch273': 'd.halverson@utexas.edu',\
          'etf890': 'e.fortin@utexas.edu', 'nve360':'n.ehrmann@utexas.edu'}

aliases = {'mis918', 'etf890', 'nve360'}

groups = [
    names[a]+' ('+ re.sub(r'^(\w)\.(\w+)(?=@)', lambda m: m.group(1).upper() + '.' + m.group(2).capitalize(), emails[a]) +')'
    for a in aliases if a in names and a in emails
    ]

print(groups)
# ['Marquita See (M.See@utexas.edu)', 'Elvia Fortin (E.Fortin@utexas.edu)', 'Nakisha Ehrmann (N.Ehrmann@utexas.edu)']
```